# PHP script for download and delete file works on desktop but fails on android

Tags: php, android

I have a script that download a pdf file and then delete it. This script create an instance of a class Document, then call the download() method of Document.
This is the code:

```
public function download($data = null){
    if (file_exists($_SESSION['__config__']'html_root']."/".$this->getFilePath().$this->file)){
        $this->downloadFile();
        $this->deleteFile();
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['no_file']['file'] =  $_SESSION['__config__']['html_root']."/".$this->getFilePath().$this->file;
        header("Location: no_file.php");
    }
}

public function downloadFile(){
    $mime = MimeType::getMimeContentType($this->file);
    $fp = "../../".$this->getFilePath().$this->file;
    header("Content-Type: ".$mime['ctype']);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$this->file);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    readfile($fp);
    //exit;
}

public function deleteFile(){
    if (file_exists("../../".$this->getFilePath().$this->file)){
        unlink("../../".$this->getFilePath().$this->file);
    }
}
```

When I download the file on Android I get a corrupted PDF file, containing the no_file.php html code.
Without `$this->deleteFile()` I get the correct pdf file on Android, also.

Comment: My guess: Since you are not waiting for the download to be complete you are deleting the file before all information is transmitted. Is readfile blocking?

Comment: I think so, but... why only on Android?

Comment: Can you try just to comment the deleteFile() function out for now and test if it works on Android then? My comment might be nonsense since the buffer should be filled nontheless.

Comment: Already done: if I comment that function, it works on Android too. If i put a `sleep(5)` line before deleteFile() call, on Android the download takes 5 seconds more then usual. But only on Android

Comment: Hmm. That is a really weird behaviour. It is beyond my knowledge how the Android browser differs from a desktop version so i cannot really give any more advices.